# Pandas: Non-unique multi-indexed DataFrame to Panel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, multi-index

**Pandas: Non-unique multi-indexed DataFrame to Panel**

I am new to Pandas. Is there a way to convert a non-unique multiindex to Panel retaining the non-unique data? Panel seems deprecated but an older library needs Panel that we would need to create from multi-indexed dataframe.

Sample code:

```
> arrays= 
[numpy.array(['a','a','b','b']),numpy.array(['one','one','one','two'])]
> df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(4,2),index=arrays)
> print df
> df
            0         1
  a one  1.167011  0.008832
    one  0.253517  1.101717
  b one -2.666648  1.327103
    two  0.160127 -0.186646

>df.to_panel()
  ValueError: Can't convert non-uniquely indexed DataFrame to Panel.
```

Unfortunately, we have no control on uniqueness of the multi-index. Is there a way to create a panel from non-unique multi-index similar to how the conversion happens with Panel -> Multi-index -> Panel where panel has non-unique major_axis labels (below sample). Or would we need to iterate over the values of multi-indexed dataframe and build the 3 dimensional numpy array with non-unique major_axis, minor_axis, items and pass into the pd.Panel constructor? Any help is appreciated...

---

### Panel -> Multiindex -> Panel

```
>minor_axis=['one','two']
>major_axis=['a','a','b']
>panel = pandas.Panel(numpy.random.randn(2,3,2), major_axis=major_axis, 
  minor_axis=minor_axis) # Panel is created with non-unique index labels
>panelFrame = panel.to_frame() # Panel to MI 
>panelFrame.to_panel() # MI to Panel retains non-unique index.

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: a to b
Minor_axis axis: one to two
```

Comment: You may need create the 3rd level or slightly modify the 2nd level

Comment: Thank you WeNYoBen! Adding a 3rd level to make index unique may be the way to go.